# Renaming elements using stylesheets

Tags: xslt

I have an XML file as follows, and I would like to use a stylesheet to change the attribute names to element names, and then rename the parent 'g' element to include the child's element text (if that makes sense)

Original XML

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="test.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<c version="0.1">
 <f>
  <g>
   <column name="A/B">Test_1</column>
   <column name="C/D">NA</column>
  </g>
  <g>
   <column name="A/B">Test_2</column>
  </g>
  <g>
   <column name="A/B">Test_3</column>
  </g>
 </f>
</c>
```

I would like to produce this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<c version="0.1">
 <f>
  <gTest_1>
   <a_b>Test_1</a_b>
   <c_d>NA</c_d>
  </gTest_1>
  <gTest_2>
   <a_b>Test_2</a_b>
  </gTest_2>
  <gTest_3>
   <a_b>Test_3</a_b>
  </gTest_3>
 </f>
</c>
```

This is the stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:variable name="lowerCase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
  <xsl:variable name="upperCase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />

  <xsl:template match="column">
    <xsl:element name="{translate(translate(@name,'/','_'),     $upperCase,$lowerCase)}">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This stylesheet changes the renames the element name using the attribute name.How do I rename the parent element using the element text for a child with the attribute "A/B"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add a template

```
  <xsl:template match="g">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}{column[@name = 'A/B']}">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Nqn5Y5

Comment: Thanks pal, much appreciated